# How to create a handler for parsing a xml using SAX?

Tags: java, xml, spring, sax, xerces

I'm using xerces SAX to parse this XML:

```
<product id="123">
  <sku>abc123</sku>
  <location>
    <warehouse>1</warehouse/>
    <level>3</level>
  </location>
  <details>
    <weight unit="kg">150</weight/>
    <mfg>honda</mfg>
  </details>
</product>
```

So I created my own class named ProductSAXHandler.java:

```
public class ProductSAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {


}
```

Now from my spring mvc controller I plan on pass my XML file as a string, and I want a Product object returned.

So inside my ProductSAXHandler I will create my startElement, endElement methods.

So should I just create a method that takes the xml as a string, then instantiates this ProductSAXhandler and then call parse?

This is my first time dealing with xml/sax so I'm a little unclear how to design this class.

Comment: You seem to have a handle on it, why don't you just try it and see?

Comment: just making sure I'm on the right track, man java has so many config issues I find I don't trust myself on anything :)

Comment: so I'll have a static method that returns a Product class, and in that  method I'll do:  ProductSAXHandler handler = new ProductSAXHandler(); and then set the ContentHandler to handler?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I'm gonna read a bit between the lines and focus on your actual intention...

Since you want an instance of some `Product` class that encapsulates the data from the XML, probably in a structured way by preference, you'd do much better to use [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) for this task. Unless you have really specific requirements regarding the customization of binding XML input to objects, this will turn out a lot simpler than using SAX.

What you'll need to do is:

1. Get a W3C XML Schema for your XML. If you don't have one and can't obtain one, then there are tools out there that can generate a schema based on input XML. [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) makes this very easy.
2. Generate Java classes from the schema. For this you can use XJC (the XML-to-Java Compiler) available with Sun's JDK. If you're using build tools like Ant or Maven, there's plugins available. This can automate the process to make it part of a full build.
3. Use the JAXB API with your generated classes to easily turn XML documents into objects and vice-versa.

Although JAXB will take some time to learn (especially if the desired XML-Java mapping isn't 1-to-1), I think you'll end up saving time in the long run.

Sorry if you really do need SAX and this answer is not applicable, but I figured I'd rather let you know your options before using a somewhat archaic XML processing model. Note that DOM and StAX might also be of interest to you.